# why h:commandLink not working inside datatable if bean is in session scope

Tags: jsf-1.2

i am working on jsf 1.2 application. i have kept bean in request scope and used h:commandLink inside datatable which passes rowId to bean class. But it is not working if i keep bean in request scope, i needed to change it to session scope. but there is problem of session scope as i come back to tab that uses this bean it shows previous values (Obviously),
which i dont wont.

can any one tell how to solve this problem

1>either how to use h:commandLink inside dataTable when bean scope is request or 
2> how to remove bean from session scope.

please help me out thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got solution to my problem to how to remove bean from session scope,
I have use following code when i go back to previous page :

```
HttpSession session = (HttpSession) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSession(true);  
        session.removeAttribute("someBean");
        return "prevPage";
```